# CSS HTML Button Centering

Tags: html, css, button, center, centering

I've done tons of research on this and I cannot find any answer on how to fix this. Let's get started.

I have 2 menus and an image(you can see the format in the jFiddle). I want to center the menus. Now yes I know this is usually simple, but I have tried a bunch of normal remedies which include margin, position, and padding. Please give me some help. You can play around with the jFiddle by using the link below. Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/7mXPy/1

Important CSS

```
#nav3 {
width: 100%;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 1em 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #f2f2f2;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: text-top;
}

#nav3 ul {
list-style: none;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
}

#nav3 li a {
display: block;
padding: 8px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
color: #069;
border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
vertical-align: super;
margin: 10%;
}
```

Important HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="nav3">
       <ul>
          <li><a href="#" style="float: left;">Home</a></li>
          <?php
            if($_SESSION){
                ?> <li><a href="#" style="float: left; border-right: 1px solid #ccc;">Logout</a></li> <?
            }else{
                ?> <li><a href="#" style="float: left;">Login</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#" style="float: left; border-right: 1px solid #ccc;">Signup</a></li>
                <?
            }
          ?>
       </ul>
    </div>

    <img style="margin-left: 650; z-index: 9;" src="includes/logo/diagram_v2_22.png">

    <div id="nav">
       <ul> 
          <li><a href="#" style="float: left">XBOX360</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" style="float: left">XBOX1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" style="float: left">PS3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" style="float: left; border-right: 1px solid #ccc;">PS4</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It looks like the floats are what's screw you up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `float: center;`. Use something like this:

```css
#nav ul li, #nav3 li {display: inline-block;}
#nav ul {text-align: center;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/7mXPy/6/

Comment: You, my friend, are a beautiful person. Thank you very much!